# Why is SQL Management Studio Stored Procedure breaking my rows into new lines?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql, sql-management-studio

I have a stored procedure that is set up to run once a week. However, it seems to be breaking up my lines if the length of the row is over 224 characters, right in the middle of words. The procedure runs, stores the data into an .xls file, and emails it to recipients. Does anyone know why my lines are breaking up like this?

Comment: 224 is quite a long size for a line. 80 is preferred. Have you checked the recommended settings of the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _SQL Server_ _T-SQL_ Transactional Structured Query Language?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: You can use the "_Google_" Search-Engine, for instance. You can read [questions like this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90037/ssms-2012-limit-of-characters-on-editor-window-line) where similar people have discussed the intricacies of the _Microsoft_ _T-SQL_ Transactional Structured Query Language.

Comment: The issue isn't in the text editor window. When I run the query, the results in the grid are just fine. Its only when the stored procedure puts it in an excel file and emails it.

Comment: So the length of 224 characters is related to the output, not to the source lines of code of the stored procedure. It is very difficult to get that in only three and a half lines of question description as it appears on our displays. What is the function call that creates the _Microsoft_ _Excel_ WorkBook File?

Comment: It is something similar to this:

EXEC sp_makewebtask  
    "@"outputfile = 'd:\testing.xls',   
    "@"query = 'Select * from Database_name..SQLServerTable"

Comment: Can you please edit your question in order to contain this `EXEC` Stored Procedure Call? Also, can you edit your question in order to contain the body of the `sp_makewebtask` Stored Procedure? These are both two important items.